# how does arrow function with spread operator work

Tags: javascript

How does this work:

```
 const invert = fn => (...args) => -fn(...args);
```

Specifically, what is happening with (...args). It behaves as if it is separating the arguments from the function after the first fat arrow, but I suspect there is a better, more specific, explanation. Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: Have you seen examples how this `invert` function is used?

Comment: If you want to better understand ES6, this is a great resource https://babeljs.io/

Comment: This is NOT an exact duplicate and quite a useful question for people trying to get to grips with arrow functions and spread operators. It helps to see the combination (and have it explained).